Bell crank, bell-crank or bellcrank?
Which of the following versions of the same word is best to use for documents written in international and American English?

Bell crank
Bell-crank
Bellcrank

I tried to trawl the internet for an answer, but could not find an authorative answer.

Since all three are common, you won't go wrong by picking one and staying true to your choice.

Google Ngram Viewer shows 'bellcrank' to be least common, although the Wikipedia entry calls it a bellcrank. But the Ngram shows that none of them have much currency now, perhaps there is another term.

M-W reflects US usage, and it lists the open compound (as do Collins and Dictionary.com, though the latter at least includes hyphenated examples in citations). OED and ScienceDirect favour the hyphenated form, an article at Mindat contains the closed form, and Wiktionary lists both open and closed forms.

They still seem quite common in control applications, although direct control with a small motor would be an alternative. No real reason to recommend one spelling, although you might have a general preference for open, closed, or hyphenated forms, and wish to be consistent.

I think I can offer a unique perspective because the term was unknown to me before reading this question; I am not a native English speaker.
The first form, "bell crank" tells me that we are talking about a crank which turns/actuates a bell.
The second form "bell-crank" tells me that we are talking about bell-shaped crank, or a specialty crank that is only useful for cranking bells, without saying anything of its shape.
The third form, "bellcrank" tells me that what we are talking about is not a crank, but something related to bells and cranks, or a slang term that is entirely unrelated to either.
After trying to understand the 3 forms, I googled the term, and in the process gained the bias of familiarity, but I saw a new possibility, a crank that moves like a bell (this was wikipedia's description).
Having googled the term, and seen some images, I would say that all three forms are correct in their own way, but they each refer to distinct things, and are not interchangeable in formal language, or an engineering description, if the aim is correctness.
Seeing how each of the three forms appropriately describes distinct things, I find there is not enough context in your question to know which of the distinct things you have in mind, so it's not possible to tell which form is correct in your context.
I don't think these are three versions of the same word, but rather two or three distinct words. To me, the form "bellcrank" is slang for "bell crank", but it is less ambiguous; a "bellcrank" cannot talk about a crank that turns a bell, but can only be about a crank that moves like a bell, or one that is shaped like a bell.
Hopefully the unique perspective of a mind that sees the word for the first time was helpful.

How does a difference in spacing make something "slang"? If somebody said That doesn't crank my bell to mean something like it doesn't interest me or doesn't alarm me or some such, that would be slang because the words have a non-literal meaning. Slang is about meaning, not writing.

I think this is all nonsense. By this logic, a horse shoe might be a shoe for riding / kicking horses (a shoe with a spur attached?), and a horse-shoe might be a horse-shaped shoe, leaving only a horseshoe for blacksmiths. But in reality, obviously they all refer to the same thing, and the different orthographies mean nothing at all in speech anyway.

@tchrist I suggest reasonable spacing is best with a boomslang.

Unfortunately, the answer is not an answer but a subjective opinion. It would be more helpful as a comment.

@FumbleFingers The OP asks three distinct things (google it, look at pictures), and not to a single thing described by three names. The ambiguity is in which of the three distinct things the OP's words are referring to, but in your horse shoe example there is no ambiguity that we are talking about a footware that horses wear, regardless how you spell horseshoe.

@JaredoMills: I have no idea what you mean. The OP asks what is the correct orthography for a term which only has a single referent. Your answer appears to differentiate between three different referents depending on how "the" word is spelt, which imho is nonsense. I've just checked the relevant Wikipedia page, and confirmed my expectation that all three orthographies bell crank, bell-crank and bellcrank occur within the same article - and they all quite obviously refer to the same actual thing.
